# How to shuffle with "n" number of times

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x, user-defined-functions

I have to shuffle a list by splitting it into two lists and then shuffling it n number of times. I'm having trouble making a for loop for the two lists to shuffle (for range of n) because no matter what n is. It shuffles only once.
This is my code for the function:

```
def shuffle(xs,n=1):
il=list()
if len(xs)%2==0:
    stop=int(len(xs)//2)
    a=xs[:stop]
    b=xs[stop:]
else:
    stop=int(len(xs)//2)
    a=xs[:stop]
    b=xs[stop:]
if n>0:
    for i in range(n):
        shuffle=interleave(a,b)
else:
    return 
return shuffle
```

my interleave function was defined before and seems to be working correctly.

Comment: What makes you think that the list is shuffled only once? And why do you have the `if` statement in your for loop if you're going to do exactly the same thing inside?

Comment: Use a different variable name than `shuffle`. Also, ensure a `return` from every code block.

Comment: @justhalf i edited it. that one was just me manipulating it. this is what I had where it would just shuffle one time

Comment: same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892170/how-to-shuffle-a-list-correctly-in-python/19892275 ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are wanting to interleave the lists, you can write a simple recursive function to do it n number of times.  The one thing with interleaving the list is that the first and last characters will always be the same, I believe.

```
def shuffle(lst, num):
    '''
    lst - is a list
    num - is the amount of times to shuffle
    '''
    def interleave(lst1,lst2):
        '''
        lst1 and lst2 - are lists to be interleaved together
        '''
        if not lst1:
            return lst2
        elif not lst2:
            return lst1
        return lst1[0:1] + interleave(lst2, lst1[1:])
    while num > 0:
        lst = interleave(lst[:len(lst)/2], lst[len(lst)/2:])
        print lst
        num -= 1
    return lst
```